# GIMP Screen Resolution Issue

Tags: display-resolution, gimp, 20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo Yoga 920 Vibes Windows 10, virtual box. It has 16GB Ram, 4k Resolution 3840 x 2160 host/guest Resolution. So I've changed scaling to 200% in Ubuntu.  but GIMP is not using that scaling. The toolboxes and other windows display very small icons which are hardly visible. The other applications in ubuntu display proper large icons as per scaling.
Kindly suggest what configuration needs to be changed. I've attached the image for the reference.

Regards,
Nirav Pradhan[GIMP Screen[[image: ][1][1]]

Comment: There are themes with larger fonts and icons. Also, see [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79118/gimp-how-do-i-change-ui-dpi)

Answer (score 8):

GIMP 2.10 uses GTK2, and there is no full HiDPI support possible with GTK2. The upcoming 3.0 release is based on GTK3 with HiDPI support. Here is a [link to the bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/925) tracking progress for the upcoming 3.0 release.

This [November 2020 blog post](https://www.gimp.org/news/2020/11/06/gimp-2-99-2-released/) by the GIMP team has all the details, and explains how you can try the 2.99 development release using Flatpak. With that version the icons will scale correctly as seen below (screenshot of GIMP 2.99.4 running on Ubuntu 20.04 on a 5k display). As a development release, 2.99 is not stable software.

[image: GIMP 2.99 development release with HiDPI support]